# Get value from a string after a special character

Tags: jquery, parsing

How do i trim and get the value after a special character from a hidden field 
The hidden field value is like this

Code

```
<input type=-"hidden" val="/TEST/Name?3"
```

How i get the value after the "question mark" symbol in jquery??

Answer (score 161, accepted):

You can use [`.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [`.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr) like this:

```
var val = $("input").val();
var myString = val.substr(val.indexOf("?") + 1)
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/sRBsS/1/).  If you're *sure* of the format and there's only one question mark, you can just do this:

```
var myString = $("input").val().split("?").pop();
```

Comment: Actually, lastIndexOf() is safer if you have more than one of the special characters in your string. Good answer anyways. Thanks. +1

Comment: @frostymarvelous - since this is a URL, you want to start with the first `?` since that's where the query string portion of the request begins, even if there's another later :)

Comment: actually since it is a hidden field, it can be anything. btw i only stated this since you added in your answer that if he/she is sure it contains only one ? char then use that. i found your thread looking for a way to get values after the pound char.

Comment: Attention! If ? should be missing altogether, this answer will NOT return an empty string, but the complete contents of the input field!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have your hidden input in a jQuery object `$myHidden`, you then use JavaScript (not jQuery) to get the part after `?`:

```
var myVal = $myHidden.val ();
var tmp = myVal.substr ( myVal.indexOf ( '?' ) + 1 ); // tmp now contains whatever is after ?
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var value = $('input[type="hidden"]')[0].value;
                alert(value.split(/\?/)[1]);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="hidden" value="/TEST/Name?3" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
//var val = $("#FieldId").val()
//Get Value of hidden field by val() jquery function I'm using example string.
var val = "String to find after - DEMO"
var foundString = val.substr(val.indexOf(' - ')+3,)
console.log(foundString);
```

Assuming you need to find DEMO string after - by above code you can able to access DEMO string substr will return the string from whaterver the value indexOf return till the end of string it will return everything.