# How do I get the base64 string in the base64 object?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

I want to get it after "data: application / vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document; base64,". 
I want to pull the data starting with "UEsDBBQACAgIANBmkE8AAAAA ...".
How can I do that?

**Base64 output**

```
ADDENDUMA: "data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document;base64,UEsDBBQACAgIANBmkE8AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALAAAAX3JlbHMvLnJlbHOt0sFKAzEQBuB7n2KZe3e2VURks72I0JtIfYCQzO4Gm0xIplrf3lAKulBWwR4z+efnI6TdHP2+eqeUHQcFq7qBioJh68Kg4HX3tLyHTbdoX2ivpUTy6GKuyk7ICkaR+ICYzUhe55ojhXLTc/JayjENGLV50wPhumnuMP3sgG7SWW2tgrS1K6h2n5H+
```

***React JS***

```
if(convertedResult){
    props.values.addendumA = convertedResult
    props.values.addendumA = JSON.stringify(props.values.addendumA)
    console.log('ADDENDUMA: '+props.values.addendumA)
    changeSelectedA(props.values.addendumA)
}
```

Comment: Look for the text after `;base64,`?

Comment: how can i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get value of a string after a slash in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8376525/get-value-of-a-string-after-a-slash-in-javascript)

Comment: A regex? An indexOf and substring?

Comment: Or [Get value from a string after a special character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4232462/215552)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple Regex expression

```js
const regex = '(.*)(base64,)(.*)';
var macthes = props.values.addendumA.match(regex);
var val = macthes[3]; //This is what you're looking for
```

Comment: No need to capture the first part if all that's cared about is after the `base64,`. I'd also recommend just using an immediate regex rather than converting a string.

Answer (score -1):

You can split using `base64,`, remove the first element and then join again.

```
let parts = addendumA.split("base64,")
parts.shift()
parts.join("")
```

Comment: Please don't answer obvious duplicates.

Comment: if it's a duplicate it will get closed as such

Comment: If it's a duplicate, you should be voting to close it as such, not making it harder to do so.

Comment: This may not be the right place to have this discussion, but I don't see how answering can make it harder to close it as a duplicate. I could even argue that the proposed duplicate, although answering a more general problem, does not answer this particular question. Some people may reach this page looking for exactly how to get the base64 repr from an img source and this could be faster and easier for them.

Comment: @RaduDiță When a general solution answers a specific question the general solution should be preferred. Regexes/substrings/etc. are trivially searchable; that this is searching for a specific string is immaterial.

Comment: There is plenty of debate as to the worth of answering duplicates on Meta Stack Overflow. See [Should there be a deterrent for answering obvious duplicate questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252009/215552) and [Delete an Answer if Duplicate Found After Posting?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266551/215552)